# Replace text strings in excel column using list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have a list of text strings. 
I need a formula or plugin to look up in column a if any of the cells contain a value containing one of the text strings in my list. If yes then the cell data should be replaced with the exact text string in the list and all the characters before and after removed

Comment: Can you add code of what you currently have and (optionaly) pictures with an example?

Comment: Please make the request clearer, explain what you have tried so far and perhaps what you are struggling with in this method. Clear screenshots of before and after would be advantageous too (just manual input of what you expect). Right now it just looks like you are palming the problem off to someone else rather than asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple vba code,

```
Sub findMatch()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
For i = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For j = 2 To Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        If InStr(Cells(i, 1), Cells(j, 2)) Then
            Cells(i, 1) = Cells(j, 2)
        End If
    Next j
Next i
End Sub
```

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

Column A is your data that has to be searched and column B is the list of strings.

Comment: Yes it would absolutely work. you have to change all the `cells(row,column)` value based on your requirement

Comment: @SammyMiri Please read my comments, you can change the row or column within the `cells` part